# cordova audio recording is not firing , saying navigator.device is undefined

Tags: cordova, html5-audio

I am creating  an  application  using cordova to record the voice  and save in phone  and 
    i  followed the  instruction in link
    1)http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media-capture
    2)https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html
     but it is saying that  navigator.device is not defined 
     added the plugin  regarding  the device `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`, but  it is still showing the same error.
 and in Xml  (in app/res/xml/config.xml)

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
</feature>
(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

still it is showing  `navigator.device is undefined` 
    and my code is

```
    function Fnrecord() {
        debugger;

        OpenModalDialog('Alert', 'Voice Recording' + navigator.device +, '80%', '20%');
        navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 2 });

        function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
            var i, len;
            for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
            }
        }
        // Called if something bad happens.
        //
        function captureError(error) {
            var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
            //  navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
            OpenModalDialog('Alert', msg, '80%', '20%');
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function captureAudio() {
            debugger;
            var capture = navigator.device.capture;
            OpenModalDialog('Alert', 'Voice Recording' + capture, '80%', '20%');
            // Launch device audio recording application,
            // allowing user to capture up to 2 audio clips
            navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 2 });
        }

        // Upload files to server
        function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
            var ft = new FileTransfer(),
                path = mediaFile.fullPath,
                name = mediaFile.name;

            ft.upload(path,
                "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
                function (result) {
                    console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                    console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                { fileName: name });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you added the plugin `https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git` to the App?

Comment: These are the plugins  added to the project  
D:\Projects\THDPortal>cordova plugin ls
[ 'cordova-plugin-media-capture-master',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.media',
  'org.apache.cordova.media-capture' ]

Comment: issue is fixed, cordova_plugin.js file is not  updating

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that the `device` plugin was not installed:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```